# give a specific color to highchart if name = Unknown

Tags: jquery, css, highcharts

We want to draw up bar graph of measurements we take.
If measurement is above x% then color is green, if below x% then color is red.
This works... but we also want to have a third color when the measured item has a label name "Unknown" This only occurs when the measured item is unknown, in other case it is green or red.

Code we use at the moment that does the colors:

```
 plotOptions: 
         {  
            bar: 
            { 
                zones: 
                [
                    {                       
                        value: 70,
                        color: '#d72828', // red
                    },
                    {
                        color: '#23b45d', // green
                    }                   
                ],
```

So how we get the third color in the graph based in the label name?
See [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRw5T.jpg)

Comment: You'll have to identify these values by preprocessing your data, and applying the color information directly to the point object.

Comment: Actually, it looks like the zones will take precedence over a color specified in the point object :/  http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/j3uakp67/.  But, you can cover all of the coloring with the same loop... - http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/j3uakp67/1/